# Test request with FormData in jest (without mocking)

Tags: javascript, jestjs, axios

I want to test a function with jest that makes a http post request to a server by using the javascript FormData. here is a minimal example of what this could look like:

```js
    import axios from "axios";
    async function foo() {
        let bodyFormData = new FormData();
        bodyFormData.append("foo", "myfoo");
        resp = await axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "https://postman-echo.com/post",
            data: bodyFormData,
        });
        return resp;
    }

    describe("Test", () => {
        it("foo test", async () => {
            return foo().then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                // here some testing stuff ...
            });
        });
    });
```

from my research jest cannot use the FormData(). How can i workaround that? Ive seen some solutions here on SO but all of them are somehow mocking the FormData but the probmle with that is then never a real request is send but i want to test if the real request to the real server in working. How can I do that with jest? I've also tried https://github.com/form-data/form-data but it is not working too

Comment: Maybe you can try using supertest to send form data and test endpoints, you can use an parallel express server to do it. https://dev.to/nedsoft/testing-nodejs-express-api-with-jest-and-supertest-1km6 in the method send maybe you can pass the form data. Hope it helps.

Comment: @IvanLynch Hm, thanks for your suggestion. But when i understand you corrctly this would also mean i would need to mock the axios request with some other request, which would mean I'm not really testing if my Axios request is working?

Comment: That's correct. You shouldn't perform real requests in unit tests. The server needs its own test coverage to make sure it works as expected too. In Jest, you still cannot be sure that a real thing works any way because it's not a browser. If you need to make sure it works in general, save this for e2e browser tests.

Answer (score -2):

Actually you need to use supertest module like that

```
const supertest = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');
const request = supertest(app)

describe('POST "/" root endpoint for login & authentication', function() {
    it('/register method with missing parameter returns', function(done) {
        request
          .post('/register')
          .send('username=john&password=12345') // x-www-form-urlencoded upload
          .set('Accept', 'application/json')
          .expect(200)
          .end((err, res) => {
            if(err) return done(err);
            expect(res.body.message).toBe("Username or password is not specified");
            return done();
      });
   });
});
```

Also you can check this [post](https://zellwk.com/blog/endpoint-testing/)

Comment: the answer is totally irrevelant, how to send formdata is not in the code